# How to write bug in proper format

Tags: network

I want to know the proper format in which a bug about a particular site should be written. It's a localized question. Is it legal to report a bug or will it be considered spam?

Comment: I have answered the first part of your question. Your IP issue is unrelated and is off topic for this site. I will edit it out of your question. You can ask that on [SU] but then make sure it is a well-written question. *I have a disturbing IP issue* does not give any info.

Comment: BTW What do you mean with *It's a localized question*?

Comment: How is this related to infosec?

Answer (score 1):

Jan Doggen is right: just writing an email which explains the steps to reproduce the bug, the expected result, and the actual result is enough.

If you want a slightly more structured format, I suggest you to take a look at the [Facebook bug report form](https://www.facebook.com/whitehat/report/) and to read [these](https://sites.google.com/site/bughunteruniversity/improve/help-us-reproduce-the-bug) [Google guides](https://sites.google.com/site/bughunteruniversity/improve/writing-the-perfect-attack-scenario).

If you want to be more accurate when describing the impact, you could read the CVSS 3.0 scoring criteria (https://www.first.org/cvss/specification-document) and then use [this calculator](https://www.first.org/cvss/calculator/3.0).

Answer (score 0):

If a website has a bug, just write them a mail saying that you think you might have found one. Report what you did exactly, what was the expected result, what was the actual result. Adding some screenshots will help.

How they react is nothing to worry about. A website with high quality standards (for the site and their service) will either inform you that it is not a bug, or reply with some form of 'thank you'. Others will not even take the time to respond.